# Given 1568 bins how many data points do we need to have k points in each of the bins?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We have 1568 bins. The probability of a point falling into one of the bins is uniformly distributed (The point is equally likely to fall in any of the bins.)

We have data points. Each data points has 784 points which can fall in the 1586 bins. If I want to have k points in each bin how many data points on average do I need?

I'm tempted to think we need 2 data points for each of the bins to be filled with at least one point. (2 x 784 = 1568)
If we want k points per bin we need 2k data points on average.

Is my reasoning flawed? Why?

Comment: Do you mean $1568$ instead of $1586$?  $2\times784=1568$

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant sorry for the mistake. I've corrected it.

Comment: You have _almost_ corrected it :-)